# GCM push notification, can not send same message

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the tutorial below and i've got it to work. The problem i'm having is when i send i push notification to my phone that contains the same message,  the phone doesn't receive it. for example if i send 'hello' and then try to send 'hello' again the second one doesn't come through.

Is there a reason why you can't receive the same message through a GCM push?

[push tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: But does your GCMIntentService receive the message? If the answer is yes your notification is problably being not replaced/stacked due to the flags you can set on your notifications. Please put some code of what are your trying to do and where it fails and the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The gcm push notifications treat messages to.be distinct depending on the collapse key you put in your message so if at small intervals messags are sent with same id they are combined in one message.
Messages often don't get lost that way so post your code here for more help or just send messages with different collapse key